# How to Roll back web service call

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, transactions, transactionscope

Suppose I call a webservice to save some data to their local DB. After I get response from the webservice I check the response for following situation:

1- If failed to insert, I can easily roll back my entire code block using [TransactionScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (In C#).

2- If it was successful I try to save these state (successful state) to my database. But before save the state my database server crashed! So I need to roll back web service call!

The code sample is like these:

```
//Calling database
var response = client.InsertNewItem(data);
if(response.IsSuccess)
{
    myDb.SaveSucessfulState();
    //Commit transaction
    scope.compelte();
}
else
{
    //Do roll back stuff.
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look into WCF and transactions

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff384250.aspx